# Which countries advocated for "support bubbles" or "pods" during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, pandemic, quarantine

Which countries specifically included the concept of "bubbles" or "pods" in their communication and education campaigns to their populations during the COVID-19 pandemic?

I remember first hearing of the term "bubble" during the first COVID-19 lockdown. It was a term referring to the idea that we should only "share the air" with a small group of people (eg housemates) and keep everyone else outside the "bubble" (eg via social distance, masks, or both). I also remember some people used the term "pod". And people sarcastically made fun of each other for using one term instead of the other ("bubble" vs "pod").

However, today I can't find much information about the "bubble" concept. Wikipedia has only this short stub section describing a "Support bubble" on the [COVID-19 pandemic in New Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_New_Zealand#Support_bubble) article.

[image: gif shows the spread of COVID-19 between social "support bubbles"]

Is there a list anywhere of States and organizations that included the concept of "bubbles" or "pods" in their communication and education campaigns during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Comment: Has your research revealed this? https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fsoc.2021.730216/full

Comment: The guidance for people in England about forming a "support bubble" is still available here: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/making-a-support-bubble-with-another-household

Comment: @Daveoc64 That sounds like it might be the beginning of an answer.